# Bootstrap Form Validation not working on SharePoint ASPX Webpage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I have an issue where the jQuery validation won't work, and after clicking submit, it doesn't validate anything and submits the form.

This is the BootStrap Form input:
[image]
Upon successfully clicking the 'submit' button - Whatever was inputted in the field is stored in my SharePoint list:

[image]

This is the column in the SharePoint list:
[image]

Here is the code that I have:

```js
<script>
  $.validator.setDefaults( {
   submitHandler: function () {
    alert( "Submitted!" );
   }
  } );

   $( "#signupForm1" ).validate( {
    rules: {
     ACI_client-name-input: "required",
    messages: {
     ACI_client-name-input: "Please enter the Client name",
    
        /* THIS PART WAS PUT IN FROM GUIDE ONLINE FOR SHAREPOINT SITES - https://redcrust.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/using-jquery-validation-plugin-with-sharepoint-2013/ */
    if ($("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("name") == undefined) {
     $("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("name", $("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("id"));
    }
    
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
     // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
     error.addClass( "help-block" );

     // Add `has-feedback` class to the parent div.form-group
     // in order to add icons to inputs
     element.parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-feedback" );

     if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
      error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
     } else {
      error.insertAfter( element );
     }

     // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
     if ( !element.next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
      $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( element );
     }
    },
    success: function ( label, element ) {
     // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
     if ( !$( element ).next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
      $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( $( element ) );
     }
    },
    highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
     $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
     $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-remove" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-ok" );
    },
    unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
     $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
     $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-ok" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-remove" );
    }
   } );
  } );
 </script>
```

```html
<form id="signupForm1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <label class="col-lg-10 control-label" for="ACI_client-name-input">Client Name</label>
     <div class="col-lg-8 required-after"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ACI_client-name-input" name="ACI_client-name-input" placeholder="Ex: FleishmanHillard" required><span class="">*</span>
     </div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="form-group row col-lg-8">
  <button type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='//fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/emplsrv/missupport/pages/MailChimpIntake.aspx'">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JSFiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/6ysz2eLc/3/

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the "-" with "_" in the ID of the input tag.

Modify "ACI_client-name-input" to "ACI_client_name_input".

The example code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jquery validate</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,WikiField,_dlc_DocId,_dlc_DocIdUrl,_dlc_DocIdPersistId"><xml>

<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-50</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">56166d47-3111-4d9e-86c4-34fc0308c55f</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://sp2013/sites/team/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-50, 5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-50</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert( "Submitted!" );
        }
    });

    $("#signupForm1").validate( {
        rules: {
                ACI_client_name_input: "required"
        },
        messages: {
                ACI_client_name_input: "Please enter the Client name",
        },      
        /* THIS PART WAS PUT IN FROM GUIDE ONLINE FOR SHAREPOINT SITES */
        //if ($("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("name") == undefined) {
        //  $("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("name", $("input[title='ACI_client-name-input']").attr("id"));
        //}

        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
            // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
            error.addClass( "help-block" );

            // Add `has-feedback` class to the parent div.form-group
            // in order to add icons to inputs
            element.parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-feedback" );

            if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
            } else {
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }

            // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
            if ( !element.next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( element );
            }
        },
        success: function ( label, element ) {
            // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
            if ( !$( element ).next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( $( element ) );
            }
        },
        highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
            $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-remove" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-ok" );
        },
        unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
            $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-ok" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-remove" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="signupForm1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <label class="col-lg-10 control-label" for="ACI_client-name-input">Client Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8 required-after">       
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ACI_client_name_input" name="ACI_client_name_input" placeholder="Ex: FleishmanHillard" required/>
            <span class="">*</span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-lg-8">
        <button type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='//fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/emplsrv/missupport/pages/MailChimpIntake.aspx'">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]